# Performance in XML layout vs layout in code?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Is there any performance difference between layouts done in code vs XML layouts in android?

Comment: Anko uses "code approach" and it is significantly faster. Please, take a look https://medium.com/@c2q9450/performance-comparison-building-android-ui-with-code-anko-vs-xml-layout-cc0abb21c561

Answer (score 2):

Yes. XML layouts need to be loaded, parsed and inflated to generate the View. Behind the scenes the `LayoutInflater` does exactly what you would do when writing layouts through code, but with the overhead mentioned before.
Here is an interesting article on this topic, which covers View generation through code, also it is about a library written in `Kotlin`: https://nethergrim.github.io/performance/2016/04/16/anko.html

**But** even though there is a performance win, I would not recommend to write layout in code for the following reasons.

- You couple your layout and your business logic. That's always bad.
- You can't use the features of the `AppCompatDelegate` (loading Views for the latest Androind version. E.g. an `AppCompatButton` instead of a normal `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, i can make one difference. Please correct/enhance my answer if possible.

1. For **XML based**, In compile time, the ID generated and stored in R file which we use to refer to that any particular layout(like TextView, Button etc.) inside our code. As the reference ID is getting generated at compile time, so at run time this overhead is not there and it is faster.
2. In **code based**, all things done at run time which makes the app slow. It is not that much visible if small number of layouts are there. But if you are creating a lot of Layouts pro-grammatically, then you may realise the slowness in your app.

Comment: People down voted both your answer and my question. I really don't understand why and why don't these down voters leave any suggestions.

Comment: @ Android Killer .Hi. can you help me for my question ? stackoverflow.com/q/46790086/4813855 Thanks a lot

Comment: For both XML based and code based approaches all things done at run time. But in case of XML there are a lot more of complicated actions. Code based approach is significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to imagine that using XML would ever be faster.

Android SDK has a lot of performance tweaks to make loading and parsing XML fast. in recent times, if you use data binding to replace findViewById this dramatically improves performance as well as each call to findViewById parses the XML tree. Where as databasing will only parse the tree once.

Also, using include in XML allows for reuse of Views which improves performance especially in cases where you would have large object churn. There is all sorts of I eternal caching and pooling of objects as well so it's possible that inflated objects are cached/pooled and cloned for subsequent use reducing the overhead on using XML. I know this is definitely the case for Drawable assets hence the need to call mutate if you ever plan on modifying one.

There are scenarios where code would be slower, with every View you create and add to your layout, you will trigger a measure and layout pass, so if you try to build a complex, deep nested layout using code at runtime, this would take a lot longer to load.

There are other factors to consider, like:

- styling is hard if not impossible to apply at runtime.
- code with views created complete runtime mY be complex, hard to maintain and bug prone.
- You can use ConstraintsLayout to flatten your views hence avoid writing custom ViewGroups if performance is an issue.
- XML allows use of the editor to preview and debug your layouts.

If the ViewGroup you want to create is simple, or simply want to create a single View and insert it into a ViewGroup, doing it in code is probably hard to beat by any criteria.

If you want to do something a lot more complex, using XML and all its features like ViewStub, includes, DataBinding is probably the way to go. I have noticed that inflating Views can be visibly slow, if you do it a lot, hence the ViewHolder pattern, but if you're careful, it's hard to justify ever building Views and ViewGroups in code for any thing but simple layout additions.